# Error in checking if a string only contains digits

Tags: node.js

```js
let duration = "365460‬"
console.log((/^\d+$/.test(duration)))
```

Actual result: false

Expected result: true

But,

```js
let duration = "11"
console.log((/^\d+$/.test(duration)))
```

Actual result: true

Expected result: true

What could be the problem? Please guide me

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your result in the first case](https://rextester.com/BKIBS97773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extra character after `365460‬`, and that's why your pattern does not match!

You can use the following to diagnose such issues in the future:

```js
const duration = "365460‬";

for(let i = 0; i < duration.length; ++i) {
  console.log(`Char at index ${i}: ${duration[i]} | Unicode: ${duration.charCodeAt(i)}`);
}
```

As you may observe from the result of the above code, there is a character with unicode value 8236, which is some sort of formatting character known as "Pop Directional Formatting".

https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8236

Comment: Please don't provide answers to typo questions, just vote to close and move on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [unicode](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode) character at the end of the string which makes result false.

```js
duration = "365460‬"
console.log(duration.split(""));
console.log(duration.length); // 7 instead of 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isdigit(str) {

    let pattern = /^\d+$/

    if (str.match(pattern)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }


}
```

You can use the above function it solves the problem of detecting only numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `isNaN()` instead which would be the relevant syntax in your case

Comment: Given that the OP's use case is, "string that contains only digits", no. `isNaN` would return false for `"0xABC"` or `"-1.E+2"` Also, this doesn't solve the OP's problem in that it doesn't address what goes wrong with their example.